# How to run KIF (xctest) from command line when I have just the .app and .xctest folder?

Tags: ios, kif

I am newbie to ios world and am figuring out how to run the tests from command line.

I have the APP.app and TEST.xctest (basically KIF tests).

I am not able to figure out how to run these tests on the app (on simulator and device).

I tried using xcodebuild test with scheme set as TEST but to no use.

I was able to use xcrun commands to install the .app on the simulator.

```
xcrun instruments -w "iPhone 5 (8.0 Simulator)"

xcrun simctl install booted <app path>
```

How do I run the Xctests now on the simulator ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also the .app and .xctest are folder structures in my mac

Answer (score 0):

From my side, I don't think  running KIF tests with .app and .xctests is possible.
Here is my approach that i'm using for my company project:

- KIF tests script is written inside xcode project
- We run KIF test with xctool - before run KIF tests, xctool builds the app and install to device, then KIF script will be run then. ( you dont have to do stuffs like exporting .app )